# DD4T Dynamic Links weird URLs

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, dd4t, linking

We're using DD4T and in a view are rendering component links.  The issue is that the link comes out like this: `http://localhost:889/http://localhost/...`.  The relative path is correct, but the front part of the URL is all messed up.

The code that runs is `DD4T.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkHelper`, `GetResolvedUrl()` function:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourcePageUri) 
    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeComponentTemplateUri))
{
  link = LinkFactory.ResolveLink(component.Id);
}
```

The link that is returned is what I've shown above.  It seems like this could be related to the Unity configuration, but I just can't quite pinpoint it.  Would anyone please shed some light here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

This is, of course, not related to DD4T and just the basic configuration in `cd_link_conf.xml`.

What needs to be specified is the `Host` element.  As per the comments provided in the boilerplate `cd_link_conf.xml` file, specify the `Domain`, `Port` and `Path`.  In my case, the Path was set to "`http://localhost`" and the domain was set to "`http://localhost:889`" causing dynamic linking to spit out the weird URL.

[image]